# My ResultSet is always closed when I return it from my method

Tags: java, resultset

I have the following class:

```
public class Refunds {
    ResultSet dataToHash = null;

    public Refunds (String UrnId) {
        Database db = null;
        CallableStatement callable;
        String query = "select * from testmdb.dbo.ApEdiZcusSaSendFile where SourceID='LAN' and UrnID=?";    

        // Get database connection
        try {
            db = new Database("jdbc/refund");
        } catch (NamingException | SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }                        

        // Run the query
        try {
            callable = db.connection.prepareCall(query);
            callable.setString(1, UrnId);
            dataToHash = callable.executeQuery();            

        } catch (SQLException s) {
            System.out.println("A SQL exception was thrown while running the query: ");
            s.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("A general exception was thrown while running the query: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            db.closeConnection();
        }                
    }

    public ResultSet getDataToHash() {
        return dataToHash;
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
// Get the result set
Refunds refunds = new Refunds(urnId);
ResultSet dataToHash = refunds.getDataToHash();
```

However, every single time `dataToHash` is `.closed()`. I don't close my `ResultSet`. Whatever the problem is, how can I modify this code so that when I get it, it won't be closed?

PS - Just ignore my old school System.outs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You close the connection, and that closes the ResultSet.

Instead of storing the ResultSet in a class member, store it in a local variable inside `Refunds`, and read all the data from it before returning from the `Refunds` method and closing the connection.

Comment: At some stage I have to close the connection though. Where would I move it to then?

Comment: @Relborg Don't return the ResultSet at all; extract what you need from it, put the extracted data into an appropriate Collection and return that instead.

Comment: @JonK I would completely agree with you, but, I was instructed to return a ResultSet unfortunately by my senior dev...

Comment: @Relborg In that case, ask your senior dev when to close the connection.

Comment: @Eran... Here goes nuthn'

Comment: @Relborg That's only possible if you keep both the Connection and the CallableStatement that were involved in acquiring that ResultSet open until the ResultSet is no longer needed. Which could be a *long* time.

Comment: @JonK That's what I was thinking, and that's because it's passed as reference and not by value right? What if you then rather copy the VALUE of the ResultSet to another reference object to hold. That way you can first copy it to the new ResultSet object, and also allow you to close the connection and CallableStatement without affecting the original ResultSet e.g. closing it.... ?

Comment: Okay so my senior dev explained it to me.. Basically it's impossible, @JonK last message above explained it all.